# Is this Valid PHP? Complex If statement

Tags: php, post, syntax, foreach, if-statement

can I do something like

```
if($x != (y&&z&&r&&w))
```

Or do I have to write it like this

```
if($x!=y && $x!=z && $x!=r && x!=w)
```

Just wondering because I have lots of variables to compare and just wanted a more elegant solution.

You might have a more elegant solution anyway. Here's what I'm trying to do.

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
        if($key != 'category_id'){
            $cp[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
```

And I have about 6 more variables to compare in my $_POST statement and I would like to make the code pretty. It's basically a huge form that needs to format into a specific array ($cp[]) with specific keys to use my MySQL insert statement.

Any fancy ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first portion of code :

```
if($x != (y&&z&&r&&w))
```

will evaluate the constants `y`, `z`, `r` and `w` *(strings `'y'`, `'z'`, `'r'` and `'w'`, if those constants don't exist)* ; doing a `AND` between each one of those.

And, then, the result of this `AND` will be compared to `$x` -- which will be considered as a boolean.

So, **no, it's not quite doing what you hoped for** ; you must use your second portion of code :

```
if($x!=y && $x!=z && $x!=r && x!=w)
```

Note that here, too, it'll search for constants called `y`, `z`, `r` and `w` *(or strings, if those constants still don't exist)* -- you should probably put some `$` in front of those, if you expect them to be treated as variables.

If you want to test if a variable has one of several values, a possible solution is to put those values into an array, and, then, use the [**`in_array()`**](http://fr.php.net/in_array) function :

```
if (in_array($x, array(10, 20, 30) )) {
    // $x is one of those values : 10, 20, 30
}
```

Some think it's easier to understand this way than writing several comparisons -- I sometimes use this myself, and kind of like it.

Comment: Of course, I was just using shorthand. to represent variables/strings/integers, whatever. I will have something more concrete to compare it to. IE if($key != $x && $key != $y). Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to write the long form or use `in_array` and an array containing your values.

Answer (score 1):

You you can **not** do it like this:

```
if($x != (y&&z&&r&&w))
```

They have to be separated out in to 4 comparisons.

Alternatively, what you can do is stick the values in an array and have only 1 comparison:

```
$skip_keys = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');

foreach ($_POST AS $key => $value) {
    if ( ! in_array($key, $skip_keys)) {
        // Continue
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This was more the solution that I was looking for. Elegant, small, easily managed.

Answer (score 0):

You can't say

```
if ($x != (1&&2&&3))
```

like that

I also was wondering in my early years whether we can do

```
if (1 < $x < 5)
```

and the answer is no too.   But you can use `in_array()` to test if something in an array for you to check several values at once:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation, if you're doing this comparions multiple times, is to write a function that validates your requirements for it. So you'll pass in your '$x' and can compare that to everything you need, and will get a boolean result. The function can be structured nicely with ifs and elseifs and you'll keep your code cleaner.

So, example...

```
<?php
// random, bad logic, but you get the idea
function validateThisThing($x) {
    $toReturn = false;
    if ($x == 'this') {
        $toReturn = true;
    } elseif ($x == 'that') {
        $toReturn = true;
    }
    return $toReturn;
}
```

Then you can just use that function as needed and keep your checks cleaner and more structured as your function name will bring context into what's being checked.